# how to send android Large sqlite data to server with volley

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley

i have 30 tables with large data(4000 row and 20 column in each table) in database sQlite  android. i want send all table to server with volley.how do it?

Comment: Is every row 1 MB data? Can you start subject and your sentences with capitals? It's no chat room here.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this question yet? I have a similar question and need help